Setting primary key in Realm MongoDB
I am trying to make a collection of cocktail recipes. In this case, every recipeName field in Realm object is unique. Then can I set recipeName to be the primary key so that I can call useObject() using recipe names?
I have setting for the _id as my primary key for now. I want to delete _id field and set primary key to recipeName. Is this possible and appropriate in db setting?

In MongoDB, _id is reserved as primary key field. There are 2 ways to achieve your described behaviour: 1. assigning the content of recipeName to _id 2. You can set a unique index on the field recipeName

then there is no way to change primary key field to recipeName?

I am guessing that you might prefer method 2. Just set a unique index on the recipeName field

But I am using Realm with Device Sync so I am not sure if unique index for MongoDB works same way in Realm

It's often good practice to disassociate a primary key from the other properties.
There's a number of reasons but here's a big one: suppose a recipe primary key is _id: Cherry Turnover. A week later it's pointed out that the turnover is actually a tart. So you go to change the name to Cherry Tart.... and you can't; Primary keys are immutable! You would have to read the object, delete the object and write out a new object just to change the name.
That would also break any existing relationships with other objects!
If the goal is to call useObject to retrieve an object by it's primary key, you would have to know the primary key to begin with. e.g. to present a list of recipes a user can choose from would require those objects to be read in to get the titles. During that process your code would know the primaryKey of each object along with the title anyway. So your recipe model would looks like this
class Recipe extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: 'Recipe',
    properties: {
      _id: 'int',
      recipe_title: 'string',
      recipe_steps: 'string'
    },
    primaryKey: '_id',
  };
}

So if you need to update the object, for example, the _id is available as part of that object.
If the goal is to guarantee unique-ness, simply query the database to see if the recipe name exists before writing.
